# Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField. in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I used to below

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cat');
        $result = $qb
            ->select('IDENTITY(c.name) AS catname')
            ->leftJoin("CatalogueBundle:Product", 'p',
                Join::WITH,
                'cat.product = p.id')
            ->leftJoin("CatalogueBundle:Category", 'c',
                Join::WITH,
                'cat.category = c.id')
            ->where('p.id =:product')
            ->setParameter('product',$productId)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        return $result;
```

to get the data from two queries in symfony2  but it gives below error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 18 near 'name) AS catname': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.
```

there is a field name in `CatalogueBundle:Category` entity. cant find why happen ?

Answer (score 3):

The `IDENTITY` function is only useful when you want to use an association as a simple field, to avoid useless join (due to DQL syntax).

In your case, `c.name` is not an association so the `IDENTITY` call is useless. Just write:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cat');
$result = $qb
    ->select('c.name AS catname')
    ->leftJoin("CatalogueBundle:Product", 'p',
        Join::WITH,
        'cat.product = p.id')
    ->leftJoin("CatalogueBundle:Category", 'c',
        Join::WITH,
        'cat.category = c.id')
    ->where('p.id =:product')
    ->setParameter('product', $productId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
return $result;
```

By the way, if I understand your model correctly, the query can be simplified as:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('cat');
$result = $qb
    ->select('c.name AS catname')
    ->innerJoin('cat.category', 'c') // left is useless, you get null c.name
    ->where('IDENTITY(cat.product) = :product')
    ->setParameter('product', $productId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
return $result;
```